# Processes is getting killed randomly on REdHat

Tags: redhat, java, node.js, kill-process, oom-killer

We have around java virtual machines with limited memory, and MongoDB.
Deployed processes are **randomly getting killed/terminated abruptly** in time. No matter java process, nodejs or mongodb process. We tried OOM configuration changes also which did not help us. We found no log or trace for killed processes. Thought it is a memory issue but we have enough memory.

System and Deployment Specs :

> **OS** : RedHat
>   **RAM Memory** : 32 GB 
>   **HDD** : 120 GB 
>   **Applications Deployed** : around 10 `jetty application services`, `mongoDB`, `Nodejs`, `Apache web server`

Tried in local machine with few memory loaders also, didn't work and could not be able to reproduce.

We are running out of clues...

Comment: Have you see OOM-killer logs in `dmesg` output?

Comment: If it's physical machine, run a memtest, sounds like bad RAM to me (considering you don't see OOM Killer logs in /var/log/messages).

Comment: ya Alex. But none were there.

Comment: we checked all possible logs, did not get a clue. We tried to simulate in local we failed.

Comment: Reboot the machine with a CentOS install / rescue disk and run memtest from the Grub menu of the disk.